# UITableView and CoreData - Displaying Data in Specific Rows and Efficiency?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, core-data, uikit

So, I have a Core data object, let's call it a session (Okay, that's what it actually is called), and it has four attributes (Name, Driver, Track and Car) that I'd like to show in a table view. I've had it working before, but, alas, I'm trying to make my view controllers a little more generic and reusable, so, I'm changing it up a bit. Anywho, here's what the table looks like...
[image]

Passed into the view controller is a Session, which is a subclass of NSManagedObject that CoreData whipped up for me. Driver, Car and Track are all object relationships, while name is simply a string. Driver, Car and Track all have a name attribute that I'm displaying in this table. I wanted a quick and dirty way of displaying this text into the table. So, I was doing something like...

```
NSDictionary *parameterValues = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: sessionName, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0], sessionDriver, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], sessionCar, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], sessionTrack, [NSNumber numberWithInt: 3], nil];

NSString *parameterString;
if([indexPath row] > 0) {
    if([parameterValues objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: [indexPath row]]] == [NSNull null])  {
        parameterString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Select a %@", [parameterNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
    } else{
        parameterString = [[parameterValues objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: [indexPath row]]] name];
    }
} else{
    parameterString = [parameterValues objectForKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]];
    if([parameterString isEqualToString: @""])  {
        parameterString = @"Enter A Name";
    }
}
```

This worked before I started passing the session as an instance variable, instead of keeping track of specific string, driver, car and track objects. Since [[self session] driver], would return nil when a new session object is passed, a dictionary object cannot be used. This is how I do it now...

```
//these come in handy, they're the object names (We can use KVC), and we can use them in the table titles
NSArray *parameterNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Name", @"Driver", @"Car", @"Track", nil];

//get the object for this row... (Name, Driver, Car, Track), and create a string to hold it's value..
id object = [session valueForKey: [parameterNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
NSString *parameterValue;

NSLog(@"%@", [session name]);

//if this isn't the name row...
if(object != nil)   {
    //if the indexPath is greater than 0, object is not name (NSString)
    if([indexPath row] > 0) {
        parameterValue = [object name];
    } else{
        parameterValue = object;
    }
} else{
    //object doesn't exist yet... placeholder!
    parameterValue = [@"Select a " stringByAppendingString: (NSString *)[parameterNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]]];
}
```

What I'm asking is... am I doing this right?

Thanks,
Matt - A Core Data newbie :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over thinking this. If you have a session entity like this:

```
Session{
    name:string
    driver<-->Driver
    car<-->Car
    track<-->Track
}
```

and Driver, Car and Track all have a `name` attribute, then all you have to do to populate a fixed table is ask for the attributes value like so:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
                                         forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell=//... get cell however you do it
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text=self.currentSession.name
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text=self.currentSession.driver.name;
            break;
        //... and so on
        default:
            break;
    }
    //... return the cell. 
}
```

Likewise, to get the object to pass to the detail view you just use the same switch statement to get the object associated with the selected row.

Comment: I was doing this, but for some reason I was in search of a more elegant solution. Now that I look at it, this is probably a more efficient way... -- The only this is, inside each of the switch statements, I have to check if the object is nil... which makes the statement a bit more, cluttered. Hmm, let me look at it again.. -- Thanks :D

Comment: If your worried about a nil relationship the easiest solution is to make the relationship required and then give the entity default values to display in the UI. E.g. a Session has a required driver relationship and the Driver entity has a default name of "None". That way, you get the behavior and the UI you want without any checking.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, although I thought I was insane. - Thanks :D